# Creating timer queue in milli seconds

Tags: c, windows, performance, winapi, timer

```
HANDLE TimerTask(unsigned int period,WAITORTIMERCALLBACK task, void* arg);
void main()
{
 HANDLE h1,h2,h3;

double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;  

  h1=TimerTask(2,TASK1,&Task2ms_Raster);
 h2=TimerTask(10,TASK2,&Task10ms_Raster);
 h3=TimerTask(100,TASK3,&Task100ms_Raster);
}

HANDLE TimerTask(unsigned int period,WAITORTIMERCALLBACK task,void* arg)  
{


    HANDLE HTimer =NULL;

    //set the timer to call the timer routine 
    if(!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &HTimer, NULL, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)task,(PVOID) arg, 0, period*1000, 0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }


    return HTimer;
}
```

I created a handler to handle the three tasks TASK1, TASK2 and TASK3 (function defintion is not shown). TASK1, TASK2 and TASK3 should be called for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. I specified in the above code period*1000 for milli second execution but when I run the application, it is executing very slow. Could anyone please identify the mistake ??

Comment: The mistake: Windows is not a realtime system. If you want better timers, you should use multimedia timers and call "timeBeginPeriod(1)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop multiplying "period" by 1000 in the call to CreateTimerQueueTimer.  Otherwise, you are specifying seconds instead of milliseconds.

In other words, change this line:

```
if(!CreateTimerQueueTimer( ..., period*1000, 0))
```

To this:

```
if(!CreateTimerQueueTimer( ..., period, 0))
```